# Using Azure to develop website then create native iOS and Android app for it later, what would be good data architecture?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-mvc, azure, windows-mobile

I have built a blog using Windows Azure and .NET MVC.
This was my only experience for web development, so I am still pretty new in this area.

I just got an idea for my second website and I plan to develop native iOS/Android/windows app for it later on.
I am going to use Windows Azure SQL database and .NET MVC again for this, but I wonder if this is good choice for my future development for mobile app as well. Can my mobile app easily get access to data hosted in Azure SQL? If so could you let me know in which way? any suggestion is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A service-oriented architecture decouples the back end from how it is displayed.

You can use SOAP or REST services to fulfill each use case.

Come up with a protocol/contract that the services expose and any client that can make HTTP requests can work with them.

Comment: REST is the flavor of choice for most web-oriented applications, nowadays. Even Microsoft is jumping on the bandwagon with MVC Web API. My understanding is that you could write a service using to handle your access to any datasource you have access to, and I would be really surprised if MS made it difficult to access Azure from WebAPI, considering how much marketing mojo they're dropping on Azure.

Comment: I would agree - I think REST is a fine choice.  SOAP has the advantage of nice tooling and brain-dead implementation.  REST requires some taste and thought, and there's no tool support.  I won't pretend to be able to read Microsoft's mind.  Don Box invented SOAP, and they've still got plenty of wizards to generate SOAP WSDL and objects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Windows Azure Mobile Services (http://www.windowsazure.com/mobile).  Mobile Services is a backend as a service you can use for your data storage from your asp.net site (from the C# code behind) and then when you're ready to build your mobile apps, you can use the exact same interfaces from the native Objective-C iOS / Java Android / .NET Windows SDKs.  This will save you from needing to write the service layer if you don't want to spend time doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your comfortable with [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), I would recommend you build the website in MVC, but then have it call into a service layer that exposes the functions desired using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

This would be an easy fit as you can then build your native mobile app later, and just call the API using JSON as the data format.

Great question by the way!